# correlation between open api and code in springdoc

Tags: java, openapi, springdoc

Im working with Springdoc to create the specification of a rest API; it is possible when you create that specification, know where it came from? For example, if I have a parameter in mi openAPI, know in which part of the code I declared that variable, so if you have something you want to change, you know where to change it... maybe the line of the code or the piece of code so I can do the search with that, I also thought of changing the spring doc lib to do something like that but seems complicated. If anyone has an idea, please comment.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty clear if you are using annotations to generate openAPI description file. Since this generation is based on your annotated Controllers, it will be pretty simple to find where the parameter is declared.